# Что делать, если в класс надо передать два массива?

Tags: c#

Я создал UserControl, содержащий PictureBox, для рисования графиков. В этот UserControl мне надо передавать два массива: координаты по X и координаты по Y.

Как с помощью индексатора передать в класс один массив я знаю, а как передать второй массив?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду обратиться к классу как к двумерному массиву? т.е. например a[19][3]?

Comment: Мне кажется, человек спрашивает о том, как создать у класса два разных индексатора с одинаковыми параметрами.

В C# нельзя.

Comment: @Modus, по поводу "нельзя" - можно ввести 3 параметр, который будет указывать из какого массива хотят получить данные :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В создании нескольких индексаторов (если я правильно понял вопрос) с одинаковой сигнатурой просто нет необходимости. Согласно [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2549tw02.aspx):

> Чаще всего индексаторы реализуются в
> типах, главная цель которых —
> инкапсуляция внутренней коллекции или
> массива.

Поэтому если, например, необходимо несколько индексаторов для доступа к *разным* внутренним коллекциям, то это говорит о том, что данный тип не совсем удачен.

Однако, если нужно контролировать состояние некоторых внутренних коллекций, то можно поступить так, как это сделали в WinForms - унаследовать тип коллекции (от [Collection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132397.aspx), [ObservableCollection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604.aspx), ...) и производить в его методах все проверки, etc.